# What is the Sinatra Equivelant of the Rails application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

the application.html.erb is a file that is applied to all views in rails. In a way, its the master file, that all child files are styled / structured after.

How can I use this with Sinatra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is called a "layout"; simply put a file named `layout.haml` (or `layout.erb`, or using the templating language of your choice) in your views directory and by default the contents of other views will be wrapped in it. Put the output of `yield` in the layout where the contents of individual views should go. For example:

- Haml: `= yield`
- Erb: `<%= yield %>`

If you want the result of a route to use a different layout, you can specify the name of the alternative layout view like so:

```
get "/login" do
   # ...
   haml :login, :layout => :logged_out

   # Or for ERb:
   # erb :login, :layout => :logged_out
end
```

If you want a particular route to not use any layout, pass `false`:

```
get "/" do
   # ...
   haml :home, :layout => false

   # Or for ERb:
   # erb :home, :layout => false
end
```

For more, see [the Sinatra book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#layouts).

Answer (score 0):

yeah ! it's the layout file located in /views/layout.erb
You should create it by your self or use [this script](http://rubyusergroup.blogspot.com/2011/01/discovering-sinatra-episode-2-skeleton.html) to generate a sinatra application's skeleton.